# Cursor does not get values from database

Tags: android, cursor, android-sqlite

Im trying to get some values from my database using Cursor.
My problem is that when i try to get the values out of my DB my Cursor out of bounds.
Im sure that the values that i want exists in the DB because i have other method that can get those values.
I want to get the value from `COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER`

log cat:

```
05-09 11:24:17.872: E/AndroidRuntime(4113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 11:24:17.872: E/AndroidRuntime(4113): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
05-09 11:24:17.872: E/AndroidRuntime(4113):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
```

here is my code:
putting the values:

```
public void putParameters(int[] parameters, String exercise) {

    String parametersList = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++){

        if (parameters[i] != 0)
        {
            parametersList = parametersList + " " + parameters[i];
        }
    }   

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER, parametersList);
    cv.put(COLUMN_EXERCISE, exercise);

    String whereClause = COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER + "= ? and " + COLUMN_EXERCISE + "= '" +  exercise + "'";
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_EXERCISE, COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER};

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, whereClause , null, null, null, null, null);

    if(c == null)
        ourDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    else
        ourDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, whereClause, null);
}



  public String getParameters(String exercise){

    String foo = "";

    String whereClause = COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER + "= ? and " + COLUMN_EXERCISE + "= '" +  exercise + "'";
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_EXERCISE, COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER};

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, whereClause , null, null, null, null);

    int parameter = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER);

        if (c != null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
            foo = c.getString(parameter);
            return foo;
        }   

    return foo;
}
```

Comment: Consider one thing `query` never return `null` so it won't be null. Instead it may be empty. check `if(c.moveToFirst()){}` and then get the values from the `cursor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `whereParameters` that goes with the `whereClause`.
Try this:

```
String whereClause = COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER + "= ? and " + COLUMN_EXERCISE + "= '?'";
String[] whereParams = {field, exercise};

Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, whereClause , whereParams, null, null, null);
```

Note that the `whereClause` has two `?`. For each one you need to provide a value, in the String[] `whereParams` and pass it to the query.
What it does is substitue each `?` with the correct value (in the example above with `field` and `exercise`. This protects you from SQL injection (so user cannot enter SQL commands in `exercise`.

Comment: In which method to put it?

Comment: In both. Whenever you use an SQL `WHERE` clause, then the way to use it is as I explained. You need the 'clause', which is the format with placeholders for variables (marked with '?'), and then the value of the variables.

Comment: but when i want to get data from COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER i dont know what values there is there, thats the point of my method.
so what i put in the "whereParams"?

Comment: in that case, remove the part `COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER + "= ? and "`. Your where clause will only consist of `String whereClause = COLUMN_EXERCISE + "= '?'";`, and then the params will be just `{exercise}`.